# What is the meaning of the Staten Island joke in 'Seth Brings Jon Snow to a Dinner Party - Late Night with Seth Meyers'?

Tags: game-of-thrones, late-night-with-seth-meyers, seth-meyers

What's the explanation of the [Staten Island joke at 2:13](https://youtu.be/BabsgCQhpu4?t=133) when Jon Snow visits Seth Meyers please?

> Jon Snow: It's 400 leagues North of King's Landing.
>
> Someone: So, like, Staten Island?
>
> Audience: (Laughs/Cheers)
>
> Jon: Oh, it's no island, sir.

I guess Staten Island is 400 leagues = 2,000 kilometers north of Washington DC or something which is what the guy thinks is referred to when Jon Snow says 'King's Landing' because King's Landing = the capital of the place?

It is 300km though?

https://www.distancefromto.net/

https://www.distancefromto.net/city-washington-d-c

Comment: The joke is obviously that New Yorkers think of Staten Island as far away, whereas it is of course part of NY and not far away at all (though less accessible), but it feels more suburban than NY and is "right-leaning". It's "not the city" to them. (And it even tried to secede in 1993.)

Comment: Yeah Staten Island is pretty inconvenient from the point of view of the rest of New York. I think another component of the joke is that for a lot of New Yorkers, New York (city) is the whole world. What’s the farthest someone in New York (city) can go from home while staying in the world? A place so remote and desolate it almost seems like a different world? Staten Island.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Ok thanks. You can post as answer. I'm not American or anything, so I really have no idea.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ok thanks. You can post as answer. I'm not American or anything, so I really have no idea.

Comment: @BCdotWEB 'obviously' ? :| I'm not American or anything!

Comment: @BCLC Neither am I. But it is an obvious joke and it is one made numerous times: https://www.google.com/search?q=new+york+staten+island+joke See also https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/NewYorkCity

Comment: @BCdotWEB knowing there's something to look up is a huge piece of the puzzle. it's like knowing if your position is winning in a chess or 9LX game. like if i knew it were a joke about staten island instead of a joke involving staten island.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess Staten Island is 400 leagues = 2,000 kilometers north of Washington DC or something which is what the guy thinks is referred to when Jon Snow says 'King's Landing' because King's Landing = the capital of the place?

The more plausible interpretation of what was meant when they said, "So, like Staten Island" is that they are suggesting (if read literally) that Staten Island is *like* being 400 leagues North of the setting of the skit (New York). But, the person does not mean this literally. They are using a [simile](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/simile/) as well as [exaggeration](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/mindbloggling/201908/standup-comedy-technique-1-exaggeration) as a [comedic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedic_device).